# Excluding all subproject jars from a copy task in Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, jar, shared-libraries

We have a Java webstart application and want to deploy/copy all third-party libraries into lib/ext/ and all of our project jar files into lib/ after the project has been built with Gradle.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24873826/3049015) to a previous question I was able to almost accomplish this, except that my shared project libraries are copied both to lib/ and lib/ext/. However, they should only be copied to lib/.

Now I am looking for a way to exclude all shared project libraries from this task:

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from(subprojects.configurations.runtime) 
    into project.file('lib/ext')
}
```

I was trying to add something like exclude(subprojects.jar), but I don't know how I can get all subproject jars in a parameter which I could pass to exclude().

How can I accomplish this? I am also open to other suggestions on how to accomlish the main goal of copying the libraries to the above mentioned folders.

Comment: Can You prepare a minimal working example on GitHub? I may try but setting it all up is time consuming, and I don't have much time.

Comment: Hi @Opal, thanks for your help! I have created a minimal example at https://github.com/Prom42/gradle-test . Just run `gradle build copyFiles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now solved my problem by remembering the names of the project jar files in `copyJars` and then excluding them in `copyDeps`:

```
List<String> projectLibs = new ArrayList<String>()
task copyJars(type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {    

    eachFile { fileCopyDetails -> 
      projectLibs.add(fileCopyDetails.name)
    }
    from(subprojects.jar) 
    into file('lib')
}

task copyDeps(type: Copy, dependsOn: copyJars) {

    eachFile { fileCopyDetails ->      
      if (fileCopyDetails.name in projectLibs){
        fileCopyDetails.exclude()
      }
    }
    from (subprojects.configurations.runtime)
    into file('lib/ext')
}
```

If somebody has a nicer solution I would be really happy to hear it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter solution:

```
task copyDeps (type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
    from (subprojects.configurations.runtime) {
        subprojects.jar.each { it.outputs.files.each { exclude it.getName() } }
    }
    into project.file('lib/ext')
}
```