# Copy jar from dependent Project in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle

I have to gradle projects `core` and `main`. They are in a flat project structure:

```
/
/core
/main
```

Both projects use the java plugin. The `main` project has a `settings.gradpe` file with the following content:

```
includeFlat "core"
```

The `build.gradle` of `main` is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
... 
dependencies {
   compile (project(':core'))
}
```

When I execute the `build` task on the main project. The core project is build first and the generated `core-1.0.jar` is used as dependency for the compile task of `main`.

When I use the `build` task on `main` I want that the `core-1.0.jar` from the `core` project is copied into the `lib` folder of my `main` project.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: This thread might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868668/copy-all-created-third-party-jars-into-a-single-folder-with-gradle

Comment: @max246 Is it possible to run the copy task right after the compile task only with calling the compile task?

Comment: You can add an action to compile task that will be executed when all previous actions are finished. Hint `doLast`.